# How to replace space with hyphen in C#

Tags: c#

I have following url.

```
http://dubaiexporters.com/searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Auto%20Spare%20Parts
```

I wanted to replace %20 to hyphen...how should i change it?
I tried using following line.

```
var encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBoxSearch.Text).Replace("-", "%20");
```

Comment: you gave parameters wrong. First what to replace, then with what. So `.Replace("%20","-");`

Comment: You've got the parameters of Replace the wrong way round.

Comment: Have you looked at the arguments you're supposed to provide for `.Replace`? They are called `oldchar`and `newchar` in that order. Please try to read the documentation before you ask a question, thank you.

Comment: i made the correction but still it is showing the same in the url..

Comment: My .aspx line of code looks like this..<li><a href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&amp;subcat=Auto Spare Parts">Auto Spare Parts</a></li>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first replace '%20' with '-'. And after that you can go with HttpUtility.UrlEncode. Please look on to the code. I tested it on online emulator (http://rextester.com/)

```
string url=TextBoxSearch.Text;
url=url.Replace("%20", "-");
Console.WriteLine(url);
var encode = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
Console.WriteLine(encode);
```

Comment: It is working fine.The hyphen is coming in the url but the problem now coming is that the contents of Auto Spare Parts is not displaying..http://dubaiexporters.com/searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Auto%20Spare%20Parts

Comment: Your query string have the parameter 'subcat' and the same is assigned as 'Auto Spare Parts'. And if you change that parameter value to 'Auto-Spare-Parts', you will not be getting the specific output. And the contents will not be loaded.

Comment: Hi, i think value of 'subcat' is getting from the database, and you have to change the space in the database side first.

Comment: So i have to make changes in the database then?

Comment: i tried using  lbSubCatTitle.Text = Request.QueryString["cat"].ToString().Trim() +" - "+ Request.QueryString["subcat"].ToString().Trim().Replace("-", " "); But still it is not showing the results...

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? how you will get the result.? You are only changing the text of label lbSubCatTitle. And for the label you will get the outoput as 'Automotive - Auto Spare Parts'

Comment: So according to you, i have to make changes in the database inorder to display the content..right?

Comment: I have used Replace() in the query..and now it is working fine....Thanks for your suggestion guys...:)

Comment: please select the answer as accepted solution if you are able to solve the issue at your end.